# How to bind datetime field between two string value

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, doctrine-orm

I have method like this :

```
public function getCustomDateOrders(string $startDay,string $endDay,string $food) :array
{
    $result = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select
        (
            'OrderEntity.name'
            'OrderEntity.created'
        )
        ->from($this->entityClass , 'OrderEntity')
        ->leftJoin(
            'Directory\Food',
            'Food',
            'with',
            'Food.id = OrderEntity.FoodId '
        )
        ->where("Food.id =:food")
        ->andWhere("OrderEntity.status =:active")
        ->andWhere("startDate<:OrderEntity.orderCreated >:endDay")
        ->getQuery()
        ->setParameters([
            "food"    =>       $food,
            "active"        =>  1,
            "startDate"     =>  $startDay,
            "endDay"        =>  $endDay
        ])
        ->getScalerResult();

        ->getScalarResult();

}
```

I have couple of values :

*$startDay* is equal to `"2016-010-17 00:00:00"` *(string)*

*$endDay* is equal to `"2016-10-03 00:00:00"`    *(string)*

And also `order.created` (one of `order`'s fields) is *datetime*.

I want to fetch order from order entity which has created field is between `$startDay` and `$endDay`. How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `between`:

```
public function getCustomDateOrders(string $startDay,string $endDay,string $food) :array
{
    $result = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select
        (
            'OrderEntity.name'
            'OrderEntity.created'
        )
        ->from($this->entityClass , 'OrderEntity')
        ->leftJoin(
            'Directory\Food',
            'Food',
            'with',
            'Food.id = OrderEntity.FoodId '
        )
        ->where("Food.id =:food")
        ->andWhere("OrderEntity.status =:active")
        ->andWhere("OrderEntity.orderCreated between :startDay and :endDay")
        ->setParameters([
            "food"    =>       $food,
            "active"        =>  1,
            "startDay"     =>  $startDay,
            "endDay"        =>  $endDay
        ])
       ->getQuery()
       ->getScalerResult();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And that is why we don't store dates as strings. You can still convert the string inside the query, so don't just turn off the computer yet.

Use the `str_to_date()` [function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

Lets translate it into SQL:

```
select * from yourtable
where created > str_to_date(start_day, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
and created < str_to_date(end_day, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

There we go. Give me all the rows which where created after the start_date and before the end date.

The better way would probabbly be converting your strings to dates and the use **between** like sugested.